# Jenkins API to get queue size on job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-api

I have a jenkins pipeline job which doesn't support concurrent build (as per requirement). so whenever multiple jobs are submitted, all jobs get queued.
i want to know does jenkins provide any api which can give me number of jobs in queue for that jenkins job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can access the queue API at `http://<JENKINS_URL>/queue/api/json`

Comment: yup i found out this API. But this API shows all queued jobs throughout jenkins server. I was kind of looking for api which can provide queue size for specific pipeline on jenkins server . however i have handled the issue by parsing the output and finding all jenkins jobs name in the queue list.